# how to pop multiple list at a time in Redis

Tags: list, redis, node-redis

I am using **node_redis**. I want to pop elements from multiple list at a time.
Here is my code.

```
setInterval(function () {
    redisClient.rpop('qwerty123', function (errorMessage, responseData) {
        socketData.emit('qwerty123', {
            'qwerty123': responseData.toString()
        });
        });
    redisClient.rpop('qwerty234', function (errorMessage, responseData) {
        socketData.emit('qwerty234', {
            'qwerty234': responseData.toString()
        });});
    redisClient.rpop('qwerty345', function (errorMessage, responseData) {
        socketData.emit('qwerty345', {
            'qwerty345': responseData.toString()
    });});
}, 1000);
```

It process lists one by one but I want to pop from all three list at same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a Redis transaction seems like the most simple way to solve your issue:

```
MULTI
RPOP key1
RPOP key2
RPOP key3
EXEC
```

There is more info in the [Redis transactions official doc here](http://redis.io/topics/transactions). In order to use transactions with Node.js, please refer to the client lib documentation.